# Where does the business data go in a RabbitMQ message

Tags: rabbitmq

I've been tasked with rearchitecting/repairing a flawed RabbitMQ/Elixir application. The guy who originally wrote it is unavailable.

One thing he did was to put the data of the message in the header property rather than in the payload. I don't know which is the appropriate way. I tend to lean toward payload because the data isn't a header in my mind. I've been looking for example RabbitMQ messages and while I found hundreds or sites addressing details about the message data/content/format, I can't find any tangible examples.

So my question is two-fold: does anyone know where I can find examples of the shape/format of the message, and which is the right place to put the data we are trying to send?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider posting a letter, think of the headers as what you put on the envelope and the body as what you put in the envelope. RabbitMQ is the postal system.

Comment: Excellent! This is just what I was hoping you'd say.